# Binary search Tree Java search(), when I just return true without the else, for every key, it returns true

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

In this code, why should I return true preceded by else statement, Why I can't just return true?
Please help me to understand this.

Binary search Tree Java search(), when I just return true without the else, for every key, it returns true. Please explain why to use else ?

why? Is there any other method you can suggest?

```
public class Binary_tree {
private node root;

private class node {
    private int value;
    private node leftchild, rightchild;

    public node(int item) {
        this.value = item;
    }
}

public void insert(int item) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new node(item);
        return;

    }
    var current = root;
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag){
        if(current.value > item){
            if(current.leftchild==null){
                current.leftchild = new node(item);
            }
            current = current.leftchild;

        }
        else {
            if(current.rightchild==null){
                current.rightchild = new node(item);
            }
            current = current.rightchild;
        }
     flag=false;
    }
}

public boolean search(int item){
    var temp =root;
    while (temp!=null){
        if(temp.value < item){
            temp = temp.rightchild;
        }

         if(temp.value>item){
            temp = temp.leftchild;
        }
        else // if i remove this else, for any key it return true?
            return true; // why else return true? why not just true
    }
    return false;
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Binary_tree tree = new Binary_tree();
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(9);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(7);
        System.out.println(tree.search(3));
    }
}
```

in this code, why should i return true preceded by else statement, why I can't just return true?

Comment: if you just return true without else, you leave the method with true, even if temp.value > item. Apparently that is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

The change you are suggesting will return false only if the root is null. In all other cases it will enter the loop, perform two checks and then return (true) from the method. The loop won't be rerun and there is no guarantee that the value has been found.

I also think you are missing another `else`. That method should read:

```
public boolean search(int item) {
  var temp = root;

  while (temp != null) {
    if (temp.value < item) {
      temp = temp.rightchild;        // Not found, so repeat for right subtree  
    } else if (temp.value > item) {      //*** Added the missing else HERE ***
      temp = temp.leftchild;         // Not found, so repeat for left subtree
    } else {
      return true;                   // Found, to exit loop and method
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```